Relation between four-wave vector $k^\mu = (k_0, \bf{k})$ and velocity four-vector
Question: how is a (subluminal) wave's wave-vector related to the 4-velocity (phase velocity)?
Wikipedia says that $$k^\mu \propto v^\mu \quad\quad\quad (1)$$
as stated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_vector. I'm pretty sure this is wrong.
Here $k^\mu = (k_0, {\bf{k}})$ is the wave vector, $v^\mu$ is the four-velocity (phase velocity) of the wave. (Here the speed of light $c=1$.)
Assume, of course, that $v<1$, i.e., a subluminal wave. If $v=1$ then the wave vector is null, and there is no 4-velocity.
The wave equation is
$$\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial (x^0)^2} - ∇^2f=0.\quad\quad\quad(2)$$
A general solution of $(2)$ is $f(x)=f(k_\sigma x^\sigma) = f(k_0 x^0 - \bf{k \cdot x})$. Plugging this into (2) we see that the wave vector must satisfy
$$k_0^2-v^2 (k_1^2+k_2^2+k_3^2 )=0,\quad\quad v=k_0/|\bf{k}|.$$
I believe $(1)$ is false except when $v\approx 1$. I think the following analysis is correct (writing $k = |\bf{k}|$):
$$k^σ 
= (k_0, {\bf{k}}) = k_0 \left( 1,\frac{ k\bf{v} }{ k_0 v}\right)
= k_0 \left( 1,\frac{\bf{v}}{v^2} \right)
= k_0 \gamma^{-1} \left(γ,\frac{γ \bf{v}}{v^2} \right)
= v(-k_σ k^σ)^{1/2} \left(γ, \frac{γ\bf{v}}{v^2} \right).$$
When $v≈1$, we have
$$k^σ ≈ (-k_\rho k^\rho )^{1/2} v^σ.  $$
If $v=1$, however, then $k_σ k^σ=0$ and $v^σ$ is undefined.
Agreed?

Which wave, light, electron, sound? Where fid you find Eq. 1?

I am simple referring to the wave equation as shown; it can be any (subluminal) wave. The equation (1) is found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_vector

$v^\mu,v_\mu~$ must be equal one. Is this the case with your equation ?

@Eli yes of course, this is the case for $v<1$.

If v=1 then the wave vector is not null. Its norm vanishes, but not its components.

Your wave equation is not Lorentz covariant.

@my2cts You wrote "If v=1 then the wave vector is not null. Its norm vanishes, but not its components." The wave vector most certainly is null when $v=1$. Of course the components do not vanish; it is not the zero vector!

Your reasoning is jumping all over the place. You say you are trying to be considering a wave that is not just the EM wave, but you have $v^\mu=(\gamma,\gamma\vec v)$, which means that this is EM wave with $v=1$ if you write that. The general wave vector gives phase velocity, which may well not behave the way you expect it to. You need to get more clarity before your question can be answered.

I am considering phase velocity, of course. $v^\mu = (\gamma, \gamma{\bf{v}})$ is simply the 4-vector. It certainly doesn't imply $v=1$.

Please clarify what wave you are considering and what the velocity has to do with $\gamma$.

Any subluminal wave that satisfies the wave equation. Vibrating string, water, sound... Velocity is phase velocity. $\gamma$ is introduced in order to relate the wave vector $k_\sigma$ to the 4-(phase) velocity $v^\sigma$.

Related : About de Broglie relations, what exactly is E? Its energy of what?.
